# delphi textrect with angle and wordwrap and vertically aligned

Tags: delphi, text, vcl

I want to use `Canvas.TextRect` to write something on the canvas with 90 degree angle and word wrap capability. I also want the text to be vertically aligned in the rectangle. How do I do that?

Comment: can you draw a mockup image of what is your intention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample code to create a vertical font:

```
function MakeVerticalFont(f: TFont): TFont;
var
    lf : TLogFont;
    tf : TFont;
begin
     tf := TFont.Create;

     tf.Assign( f );
     GetObject(tf.Handle, sizeof(lf), @lf);
     lf.lfEscapement := 900; // <--
     lf.lfOrientation := 900; // <-- here we specify a rotation angle
     tf.Handle := CreateFontIndirect(lf);

     result := tf;
end;
[...]

var tf: TFont;
Begin
   ...
   tf := MakeVerticalFont( mycanvas.Font );
   mycanvas.Font.Assign( tf ); // <--- assign the `same` font rotated by 90 degrees
   ...
```

**Update:** Try to render vertical text on a form:

```
    var tf : TFont;
        tmpcanvas : TCanvas;
    begin
        tmpcanvas := form1.Canvas;
        tmpcanvas.Font.Name := 'Arial';
        tmpcanvas.Font.Height := 12;

        tf := MakeVerticalFont(tmpcanvas.font);
        tmpcanvas.Font.Assign(tf);

        tmpcanvas.TextOut(50, 50, 'Am I vertical?');
        tf.free;
```

**Update 2:** I think it's better to use the [DrawTextEx Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162499%28VS.85%29.aspx) which supports text alignment and word wrapping.

My Delphi version doesn't include it in the documentation but you can see the various flags in the above link.
    Below is a sample code to see how to use it. I have disabled vertical font because it seems that word wrapping doesn't work well with vertical fonts.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var tf : TFont;
    tmpcanvas : TCanvas;
    rc: TRect;
    s : string;
begin
    tmpcanvas := form1.Canvas;
    tmpcanvas.Font.Name := 'Arial';
    tmpcanvas.Font.Height := 14;

    tf := MakeVerticalFont(tmpcanvas.font);
    //tmpcanvas.Font.Assign(tf); <--- `disabled`

    s := 'Hello world! I''m a long string';
    rc := RECT(10, 10, 50, 200);
    windows.DrawTextEx(
        tmpcanvas.Handle,
        PChar(s),
        length(s),
        rc,
        DT_LEFT or DT_WORDBREAK,
        nil);

    tf.Free;
end;
```

Note that when you want to align text in the rectangle you should use the `DT_SINGLELINE` flag.
For example this combination: `DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER or DT_SINGLELINE`, will center the text in the middle of the rectangle.

Comment: it didn't work,
my code is:

tf := MakeVerticalFont( Canvas.Font );
Canvas.Font.Assign( tf );
Canvas.TextOut(10,10, 'hello world');

but it doesn't have any angle.

Comment: @rahim asgari, check out my update. I had to use a temporary TCanvas object on which I assigned the vertical font. If I use the form1.canvas directly the vertical font isn't working, you're right.

Comment: Thx Nick D, it worked but i cant use it with textrect. i need textrect because i want my text to be wrapped. any suggestion?

Comment: @rahim asgari, what do mean you can't use it with textrect? It works with that function.

Comment: my code is: TR := Rect(100, 100, 450,350); tmpcanvas.TextRect(TR, TR.Top, TR.Left, 'Hello World');
but nothing is displayed on the screen.

Comment: @rahim asgari, the text will be drawn on that corner and upwards. So it will be outside the rect box. Try `tmpcanvas.TextRect(TR, TR.Left, TR.Top+50, 'Hello World');`

Comment: @Nick D, now i want my string to be wordwrapped in the rectangle.
as i know TextRect doesnt support multiline and word wrap.

any suggestion?

Comment: @Nick D, thx for your quick replies.
i want my 90 DEGREE ANGLED text to be word wrapped.

but i suppose that DrawTextEx doesnt wordwrap angled text.

any suggestion?

Comment: @rahim asgari, I don't know if there is a function that wraps vertical text. One possible solution (but not very good) is to use Delphi's `WrapText`. Then manually you can draw each string separated with new line chars with `TextRect`, in a loop. `WrapText` is for fixed-width chars, so the result wont be great.

Answer (score 4):

There is an Orientation property of TFont in Delphi 2006 onwards. Unfortunately the help wasn't updated to include it (like so much of D2006 help).

[Delphi 2010 help is here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.TFont.Orientation)

It is in tenths of a degree, so set to to 90 degress, use 900.

```
Canvas.Font.Orientation := 900;
Canvas.TextRect(....);
```

You also then need to adjust the rectangle co-ordinates as required.

I've used ths in the past, but can't remember the details.

Comment: Canvas.Font doesnt have Orientation property.

Comment: What version of Delphi? It does in Delphi 2006 (but not in Delphi 7)

Comment: If you are using Delphi 7 or earlier, you will need to use the method mentioned by Nick D

Comment: yah, you are right. i am using delphi 7 which doesnt have that property.